# Is flags attribute necessary?

Tags: c#, .net

I found with or without flags attributes, I can do bit operation if I defined the following enum

```
enum TestType
{
    None = 0x0,
    Type1 = 0x1,
    Type2 = 0x2
}
```

I am wondering why we need flags attribute?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enum Flags Attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/enum-flags-attribute)

Comment: Actually, I don't think it is a dupe; that dup doesn't *touch* on why it is needed; all of the examples there would work the same either way

Comment: @Marc: Hmm, I just finished looking at some of the answers and you do have a point there.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

C# will treat them the same either way, but C# isn't the only consumer:

- `PropertyGrid` will render it differently to allow combinations
- `XmlSerializer` will accept / reject delimited combinations based on this flag
- `Enum.Parse` likewise (from string), and the enum's `.ToString()` will behave differently
- lots of other code that displays or processes the value will treat them differently

More importantly, though, it is an expression of intent to other developers (and code); **this is meant to be treated as combinations, not exclusive values**.

Comment: Possibly mention ToString, as a particularly common operation?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes bit combinations of `enum` values are meaningful (like `FileAccess` - read, write, read+write), sometimes they are not (usually). So `[Flags]` is descriptive way to store in metadata information that bit operations are *meaningful* on this enum type. There are several consumers of this attribute, for example `ToString` of that enum.